# loading image into canvas with a progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to use this function to lead an image into my canvas :

```
  function handleImage(e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        var img = new Image();
       // img.onprogress = function (e) {
       //     ProgressPerc = e.loaded / e.total * 100;
       //     alert(ProgressPerc);
      //      $('#ProgressBar').css('width', ProgressPerc + '%');
      //      $("#sp_progressCount").html(ProgressPerc + '%');
     //   }
        img.onload = function () {
            // var canvas = ctx.canvas;
            var hRatio = canvas.width / img.width;
            var vRatio = canvas.height / img.height;
            var ratio = Math.min(hRatio, vRatio);
            var centerShift_x = (canvas.width - img.width * ratio) / 2;
            var centerShift_y = (canvas.height - img.height * ratio) / 2;
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            resizeContainer(img.width * ratio, img.height * ratio);

            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, img.width * ratio, img.height * ratio);
           // d = ctx.getImageData(centerShift_x, centerShift_y, img.width * ratio, img.height * ratio);
        }
        img.src = event.target.result;

    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

wish work great but now i want to add a progress bar that show the percentage of the loaded data and based on this link `http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2012/01/13/html5-image-progress-events/`
i figure out that i can use this snipet of code :

```
 // img.onprogress = function (e) {
       //     ProgressPerc = e.loaded / e.total * 100;
       //     alert(ProgressPerc);
      //      $('#ProgressBar').css('width', ProgressPerc + '%');
      //      $("#sp_progressCount").html(ProgressPerc + '%');
     //   }
```

but than i figure out that in the link those function are only proposed to be added later and browser don't support it .
so i am stuck here ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images do not have a progress event so normally you can not show the progress of an individual image. Yet I see you are using a `FileReader`..

You need to add the progress to the file reader not the image. The `img.onload` you have is only to display the image that was loaded by the fileReader .

So add your progress event handler to `reader`. Also to avoid an error in your code as the progress event does not always know what is coming check if file length is known. If the size is not known show the number of bytes loaded.

```
reader.onprogress = function (event) {
    var str, p;
    
    if (event.lengthComputable) {   // does the progress know what's coming
        p = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;   // get the percent loaded
        str = Math.floor(p) + "%";    // create the text
    } else {
        p = event.loaded / 1024;   // show the kilobytes
        str = Math.floor(p) + "k"; // the text
        p = ((p / 50) % 1) * 100;   // make the progress bar cycle around every 50K
    }

    $('#ProgressBar').css('width', p + '%');
    $("#sp_progressCount").html(str);
}
```

Comment: but i am having errors in calculations it is not giving the exact %

Answer (score -2):

I checked your link. http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2012/01/13/html5-image-progress-events/

I think you have not any function to show progress bar.

Check this code from link

```
<img id="image"
 src="sample.jpg"
 onloadstart="showProgressBar()"
 onprogress="updateProgressBar(event)"
 onloadend="hideProgressBar()"/>
```

You have `updateProgressBar` function, but you havent `showProgressBar` function. I hope it will fix bug.

If not, try to create new hidden image tag like this, and load your image there and paraller load in canvas.

Comment: `onprogress`, `onloadstart`, and `onloadend` are not `Image` events. Nor should you add events inline it is considered bad practice.